# The format type of reading a matrix from a file?

Tags: matlab, file, types, format

I saved a matrix in a file.txt; the type of matrix is as follow:

```
file: 0.010993,0.21973,0.012142,0.49897,0.24634,0.01183
```

When I open the matrix by using

```
Matrix= dlmread( 'File.txt') ) ;
```

The matlab take only 4 number after the point, where Matrix:

```
Matrix: 0.0110    0.2197    0.0121    0.4990    0.2463    0.0118
```

I don't want to change the numbers after the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

### Checking the Workspace:

Without any change and simply checking variable `Matrix` in the workspace window reveals that the full values are stored and that MATLAB is simply choosing to only display a specific amount of digits:

```
Matrix = dlmread('File.txt')
```

[image: Workspace Matrix]

---

### Changing the Display Format:

If you configure the display format to `long` you will see that MATLAB does extract all the decimals within the text file and can display them in the command window. Also opening up array `Matrix` in the workspace panel and clicking the cells also verifies that all the decimal numbers are taken into account. For more details on display options: [Matlab Documentation: Set Command Window Output Display Format](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/format.html).

*Note: "Numeric formats affect only how numbers appear in Command Window output, not how MATLAB® computes or saves them".*

```
format long
Matrix = dlmread('File.txt')
```

[image: Display Format Long Result]

---

### Extension: Checking Sum

```
format long
Matrix = dlmread( 'File.txt') ;
sum(Matrix)

sum([0.010993,0.21973,0.012142,0.49897,0.24634,0.01183])
```

[Google Calculator Check](https://www.google.com/search?ei=-6HeX-qlM6-Mggfpvp-YBQ&q=0.010993%2B0.21973%2B0.012142%2B0.49897%2B0.24634%2B0.01183&oq=0.010993%2B0.21973%2B0.012142%2B0.49897%2B0.24634%2B0.01183&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoECAAQR1DQN1icOWD7PmgBcAR4AIABUogBUpIBATGYAQCgAQGgAQKqAQdnd3Mtd2l6sAEAyAEIwAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiqj7TZrdvtAhUvhuAKHWnfB1MQ4dUDCAw&uact=5)

[image: Checking Sum of Results]

---

### Taking VPA Sum:

```
format long
Matrix = dlmread('File.txt') ;
sum(vpa(Matrix))

sum(vpa([0.010993,0.21973,0.012142,0.49897,0.24634,0.01183]))
```

---

### Playground Script:

Testing different display methods and approaches to taking the `sum()`.

```
x = [0.010097,0.19957,0.011086,0.49413,0.27437,0.010745];
sum(vpa(x))

x = [0.010097000000000 0.199570000000000 0.011086000000000 0.494130000000000 0.274370000000000 0.010745000000000];
sum(vpa(x))

%%
format short
x = [0.010097,0.19957,0.011086,0.49413,0.27437,0.010745];
sum(x)

x = [0.010097000000000 0.199570000000000 0.011086000000000 0.494130000000000 0.274370000000000 0.010745000000000];
sum(x)

%%
format long
x = [0.010097,0.19957,0.011086,0.49413,0.27437,0.010745];
sum(x)

x = [0.010097000000000 0.199570000000000 0.011086000000000 0.494130000000000 0.274370000000000 0.010745000000000];
sum(x)
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: I know that method, but it not useful for me, I want that the sum of the line ==1. 
where the sum of [x=[0.010097,0.19957,0.011086,0.49413,0.27437,0.010745] is 1 
but the sum of [0.010097000000000   0.199570000000000   0.011086000000000   0.494130000000000   0.274370000000000   0.010745000000000
] is    0.999998000000000

Comment: I get `0.999998` for both of the arrays in your comment. I'm confused? If you have your format set as `short` then it'll display 1 for both results. If you wish to ignore the format taking the `vpa()` of the arrays/matrices before the `sum()` may be an option.

Comment: Thank you very much for ur help. I have a big code, I can't change all the code, I should read a good values from the file. the sum befor and after  format long is different. vpa is not a solution

Comment: The numbers read from the text file have the same decimal digits, the only difference is there are additional trailing zeroes.

Comment: I want to read the same value of the file. that's all. I wont change the format of the reading

Comment: If you open the matrix in the workspace window without changing the format you'll see that it has read all the digits. By pressing on the cell MATLAB reveals that it has read all the digits. It's not changing the reading format simply the display format.